# Splash Screen not appearing in android

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I am developing an app using Phonegap 2.9. I have written the code for splash screen, which is working fine in Emulator but splash screen is not coming in android device. I have searched over the net and implemented the same things as they have mentioned but still my app is not showing the splash screen. So, I am not able to find out what's the exact issue?

I have written the **config.xml** whose code is as below:-

```
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000" />

<feature name="App">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Geolocation">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Accelerometer">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Compass">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Contacts">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
</feature>
<feature name="File">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Storage">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Battery">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Echo">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<plugins>
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>        
</plugins>
```

Following code is written on **index.html**:-

```
function onLoad()
{
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}        
// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady()
{
navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

Following is the code for my **activity.java** file:-

```
package in.com.testpro;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
}
}
```

Can anybody guide me how I can resolve this issue?

A little help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the latest version, and manual online:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

Best start with the HelloWorld example and go from there:

```
public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }
}
```

You need the following in your config.xml (either in www/ or res/xml):

```
<preference name="splashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
```

This should be all you need.
Obviously, the pictures have to be in the correct location as per manual...
It is good practice to HIDE the splashscreen in the onDeviceReady() function - you would't want to show it I suppose...

Hope that helps,
Cheers Chris